# db.Time Property saving time as datetime instead of just time

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using `db.time` property to save time required for a conversion:

```
my_model.conversion_time = time_taken = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(conversion_end - conversion_start), "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
```

but when i see the data in datastore viewer , it is stored as datetime object with date of 1970-01-01. Does anybody know how I can just save the time in the datastore

Comment: What is `conversion_end` and `conversion_start`? Are they datetime objects?

Comment: yes they are the datetime.now() objects

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have two inline assignments, but to get time out of a [`timedelta` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
>>> b
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 15, 10, 21, 31, 599402)
>>> a
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 15, 10, 18, 11, 251477)
>>> str(b-a)
'0:03:20.347925'
>>> (datetime.datetime.min + (b-a)).time()
datetime.time(0, 3, 20, 347925)
```

In order to store *only the time*, you need to use [`TimeProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#TimeProperty) in your datastore. It will be represented internally as `datetime`, but will store `datetime.time()` objects.

Comment: I have got time out of the datetime object successfully , but the problem is that GAE stores it as datetime object instead of just time.